# Query builder API in Cq5

Tags: aem, jcr, jcr-sql2

Hi I am implementing a Java module to fetch the pages which has a particular component.
Below is the code snippet which i use, but when running the module am getting an warning Saying that no PredicateEvaluator found for `'sling:resourceType'`.
Kindly suggest me the proper way to give resourceType property as query parameter

```
Map<String, String> predicateMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
predicateMap.put("path","/content/geometrixx-outdoors/en/men");
predicateMap.put("type", "cq:Page");
predicateMap.put("sling:resourceType", "geometrixx-outdoors/components/title");
predicateMap.put("p.limit", "-1");
QueryBuilder queryBuilder = slingScriptHelper.getService(QueryBuilder.class);
com.day.cq.search.Query queryObj = queryBuilder.createQuery(PredicateGroup.create(predicateMap), session);
```

Answer (score 5):

`sling:resourceType` is indeed not a valid predicate evaluator. You need to put it as a property:

```
predicateMap.put("property", "jcr:content/sling:resourceType");
predicateMap.put("property.value", "geometrixx-outdoors/components/title");
```

As you alre filtering type=cq:Page you have to also include jcr:content in the path to the property.